# Why treemacs is showing all home files instead of CWD?

Tags: doom, treemacs

An emacs newbie here, i'm using doom emacs and i tried to use treemacs for navigation purposes  however once i opened a project and toggle treemacs it shows the whole tree of files starting from $HOME, i saw somewhere that
`treemacs-display-current-project-exclusively` will do the trick but it actually doesn't , is this the expected behavior or am doing something wrong ?

Comment: How is the project defined - is it a git ptoject or by project.el or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I've not checked myself, but I remember I read it somewhere a long time ago that in treemacs logic:

- if you are using it for the first time, i.e., you've never manually added a project, treemacs will display the entire filesystem.
- otherwise, treemacs will become a project/workspace based navigation system.

Since you've mentioned that you are an "emacs newbie" , there is a chance that you've never added a project.

To add a project, do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `treemacs-add-project` and see if it behaves as you wish.